# I have an api that replicates the records when doing a concurrent consumption

Tags: c#

When I use threads to simulate concurrent tellers with about 20 requests.
This is executed so fast that the insertions with the reference field are repeated, since I am asking if it already exists.
I don't know how to prevent this from happening I'm using entity framework 4.5.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public sale process(Jobject json) {           
        Entity con = new Entity();//DataModel
        string id = generateId();
        string idSias = (string)jobCliente["idSias"];//must not be repeated
        var sale = con.sale.Where(sa => sa.reference == idSias).FirstOrDefault<sale>();
        if (ventaSias != null) {
            return null;
        }
        var newSale = new sale {
            id = id,
            reference = idSias
        };

        con.sale.Add(newSale);

        con.SaveChanges();

        return sale;
    }
```

Comment: Generate the id in your database

Comment: The client sends his own primary key from another system that is idSias as he makes several requests.
Id is the pk of my system, it is not repeated but I do not know why their id is replicated if I am validating that it is not repeated and the insertion difference is milliseconds.
It is like in the case that you do not want them to repeat a username.

Comment: There’s some patterns to help with distributed transactions. I suggest researching that

Comment: Add a unique index to that field and catch the unique index exception when calling SaveChanges

Comment: It cannot be unique since it handles 3 review states, canceled and approved. There cannot be more than 2 approved with the same idsias.
The code does not have that to make the case more understandable

Comment: I decided to use transactions at first it worked but I noticed that the api was blocked.
So I used the dispose statement for it after every request but it started replicating again.